# Saving MIDI data to a buffer Using C++

Tags: c++, parsing, buffer, midi, stdio

I am looking to have an Atmel 1284P microcontroller parse through a MIDI file stored on an SD card and activate solenoids to play music. I am experimenting by attempting to save an entire MIDI file to a buffer. As I understand it, the entire MIDI file is ultimately a series of command/data and other bytes. As such, I thought that I would be able to read the file using the c++ "fopen" method with a 'read byte' parameter. However, it is only returning the first four bytes of the file (the MTHD portion of the header). I could utilize a C++ MIDI library but I am honestly curious about this. This is the output:

MThd

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

FILE* midiFile;
midiFile = fopen("C:/Users/Preston/Desktop/cantina.mid","rb");
char* buffer;
long lsize;
size_t result;
fseek(midiFile,0,SEEK_END );
lsize=ftell(midiFile);
rewind(midiFile);

buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*lsize);
result = fread(buffer, 1, lsize, midiFile);
printf(buffer);

fclose(midiFile);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual length of `buffer`? Maybe there is more data read which `printf` doesn't print. And this is `C`, not `C++`.

Answer (score 0):

The first byte after MTHD is 0, so printf will only print `MTHD` since a C string ends with a zero byte. If you want to print the contents of the MIDI file you're going to need to convert the bytes of the file into hex.